# VisualStudio: remote lib headers are not downloaded when working with Suse Enterprise Server 12 SP5

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, libxml2, suse

**Problem**

I've got an issue when developing c++ application in Visual Studio using Suse Enterprise Server 12 SP5 distribution as remote build machine. The main problem is caused by libxml2.

Error logs: [Errors.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XweOe.png)

In the beginning, Visual Studio notified me that it cannot find libxml. I checked directory containing those headers and found out that libxml wasn't downloaded when I tried to load remote headers.

**Research**

Before SLES, I was working with CentOS without problems. As I understand, Visual Studio loads headers from /usr/lib/, so I compared how those distributions store installed libs. I found out that in CentOS lib files are stored in "/usr/lib" directory, but SLES keep them mostly stored in "/lib or /lib64" directories. So, I downloaded libxml sources from https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/ .

NOTE: VS failed when tried to execute "make" command, so I tried just coping “include/libxml” folder from sources to “/usr/lib/ directory”.

After it, Visual Studio downloaded that lib and intellisence has stopped showing error: "Cannot find libxml". But I still get errors of libxml absence: [Other errors.img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Lxf.png)

My **question** is what are ways to solve this problem? Maybe there exists any way to download /lib/ directory, or install this libxml to /usr/lib at start? Do libxml from CentOS will correctly work in SLES?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, **solution** founded.

I installed openSuse instead of SLES, download all necessary libs and successfully get headers. By the way, c++ application which built on openSuse, could launch on SLES without any problem.